# Entity not being added to another entities collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have an app when a user can create an event and then add a photo to that event once the event has been created. This is the Event entity:

```
public class Event
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public AppUser Creator { get; set; }
        public int CreatorId { get; set; }
        public ICollection<EventPhoto> Photos { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the EventPhoto entity:

```
[Table("EventPhoto")]

    public class EventPhoto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string publicId { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public Event Event { get; set; }
        public int EventId { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a method in my controller which adds the photo to the existing event. This is how the method was previously configured:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<bool>> AddPhoto(IFormFile file, int id)
  {
            var existingEvent = await _eventsRepository.GetEventByIdAsync(id);
       
        var result = await _photoService.AddPhotoAsync(file); 

        if (result.Error != null) return BadRequest(result.Error.Message);

             var photo = new EventPhoto // This correctly creates the EventPhoto class and assigns the URL and public id correctly
            {
                Url = result.SecureUrl.AbsoluteUri,
                publicId = result.PublicId

            };

            existingEvent.Photos.Add(photo);

            return await _context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;

}
```

With this code, the error: `object reference not set to an instance of an object` was being thrown at this line: `existingEvent.Photos.Add(photo);`.

To prevent this error, I added the null conditional operator: `existingEvent.Photos?.Add(photo);`. This prevented that particular error being thrown at that line of code but the issue I have is that the photo entity is not being added to the existing events photos and therefore the `_context.SaveChangesAsync()` is not being triggered as there haven't been any changes to the entity.

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `existingEvent.Photos` is null.

When you do `existingEvent.Photos?.Add(photo);` that's just skipping the `Add` when it's null.

You should try doing the below, which will assign and create a new List if it's null and then adds the `Photo`

```
existingEvent.Photos = existingEvent.Photos ?? new List<EventPhoto>();
existingEvent.Photos.Add(photo);
```

Comment: Great thanks! That seems to have resolved that error. I seem to have a different error now but I'll have to investigate that separately. Just so I know what's happening here...the ?? null coalescing operator checks whether `existingEvents.Photos` is null and if it is, a `new List` is initialized. The Photo can then be added to the Photo's list as it has been initialized. Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah, that's right, where as `existingEvent.Photos?.Add(photo);` would be equivalent to doing `if(existingEvent.Photos != null) existingEvent.Photos.Add(photo)`.

Comment: Thanks for your help